# Does science provide the most accurate depiction of reality for analyzing and describing an accurate worldview?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, empiricism, popper, materialism, popular-science

I've been fighting throughout my philosophical reading with the question of the necessity of science as the only permitted view we (since the late 19th century) have on the world.

My question might appear to be overreaching, but I don't know how to say it more precisely, because the whole question is what I'm interested in - can we have a non-science (or, as Popper would call it - pseudo-science) view of the world as we analyze reality? Must all writing today be done only by qualified scientists; in order to post academic articles? Do we have to apply for every conceivable topic, an empiric, mostly materialist, view in order to act in the 21th century academic world?

Edit (tell me if this should be different question):

Another aspect of this question is - SHOULD science be the only worldview we have in analyzing our world?

Edit (2):

For all the conversations I had regarding scientism in the comments [this is an example dialogue](https://www.google.co.il/amp/s/amp.theguardian.com/science/2012/sep/09/science-philosophy-debate-julian-baggini-lawrence-krauss#ampshare=https://www.theguardian.com/science/2012/sep/09/science-philosophy-debate-julian-baggini-lawrence-krauss) between a scientist and a philosopher on the subject that presents (though with great lack of philosophical aspects) the scientism argument.

Comment: "Do we must be scientists (today), in order to, let's say, post academic articles?" It depends; if you want to post an article on physics or biology, then YES, you must be a scientist. If you want to post an article about astrology, you have to post it to an astrology "network".

Comment: It is more a "social" issue: the scientific worldview is not "compulsory", but if you want to "play the game of science" (i.e. to be a scientist) you have to follow the rules of the game: submit papers to peer reviews, and so on.

Comment: Read "Quantum Physics and Ultimate Reality: Mystical Writings of Great Physicists" edited by Michael Green. Science has its limits as it can not go beyond the sensual universe.

Comment: I would say the question is unclear because it asks about norms (what one should or must do or believe). But what kinds of norms are you after? There's no law against believing anything, of course. There are institutional and social norms that drive scientific activity, and one can be excluded from a social group (for example scientific community) for not following them. Finally there are epistsmic norms discussed by philosophers: what is rational to believe?  So is your question about the implicit norms behind scientific activity, or more about what it is rational to believe?

Comment: And as a short provisional answer, I would say that science is not really a worldview if not interpreted.

Comment: I personally beleive a "science" view of the world is nothing more than 21st century religion these days. As most science you hear about has little to do or more complex level of thought than taking averages of some data. Sadly I fear this veiws maybe what lead to nazis in ww2. It becomes about pushing pre-existing agendas with "science". But even then we have seen how someone can read the bible and interpret some pretty wild things from it. Perhaps it's just nature doing it's thing. Who knows.

Comment: I think your questions are very good and I hope you save them in a safe place. Here is my question:  How does the Academy transmit general knowledge to the public in the future?  Not just general knowledge about, for instance, nutrition <smile> but to the big questions we get here about life, ethics, ultimate meaning, value problems, etc. Can philosophy get the epistemologists to agree to some general answers for these people? :)

Comment: Your question about "should", you understand the problems of "the Will", I don't think it can be pacified and satisfied at this point because, narrowly speaking,  there are many, many problems to solve, and science, technology and engineering are heavily involved with them.  (On this see Freud, Discontents  & Marcuse from his Eros forward.)  We are in a tough situation now of when is enough, enough;  but we are almost compelled to move forward with technology and the totally administered individual, society, etc. Difficult.

Comment: I find the question unclear so difficult to answer. You might also like 'Quantum Questions' edited by Ken Wilbur for the views of the early quantum pioneers. I would say that natural science cannot give us a world-view since it doesn't address any profound questions about Nature and Reality. It can be used to test our world-view to some extent and root out many mistaken views but it is silent on all the major questions.    . .

Comment: @PeterJ but it does give us the big bang and evolution theory and neuroscience and all these topics that give us a clear world view (at least that's what I think of it).

Comment: @Gordon thank you for those statements, I agree with them all :)

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - I suppose it depends what you call a world view. We certainly know more about the things you mention these days, but nothing that would make any difference to,. say, the world-view of Lao Tsu or Heraclitus. Physics is middle-management stuff, while the important decisions affecting world-views are made in metaphysics. .    .

Comment: @PeterJ so you're saying physics discoveries can't/won't/shouldn't affect our metaphysics views? But that what happened throughout history, one of the biggest examples is Copernicus.

Comment: Copernicus may have affected the metaphysical views of some philosophers but he made no difference to metaphysics because a geocentric universe is not a metaphysical theory. Physics and metaphysics inform each other in the sense that neither can contradict the other, but they occupy different domains. The confusion begins when metaphysical and religious theories are treated like scientific theories, as tends to happen with atheism and materialism.

Comment: @PeterJ "Copernicus may have affected the *metaphysical* views of some philosophers but he made no difference to *metaphysics*" - this seems contradicting. True, the geocentric universe in not a metaphysical theory, but it affects the metaphysical views - which is all I claimed in my previous comment.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - It seems to me we're not disagreeing. Theories and views may change but metaphysics today is the same set of problems that it was before the name was invented. No scientific data is going to change metaphysics but it can change our theoretical preferences.

Comment: @PeterJ I don't understand the distinction you make between "theories views" and "metaphysics".

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - What I mean is that our metaphysical views may change but this doesn't change metaphysics. Theories that failed in Plato's time still fail today, and in our academic community it is not obvious that philosophers have moved on. Of course, the zeitgeist may change, as we see from the emergence of materialism, but it is the guesswork that is changing, not the results of analysis. . .   .

Comment: @PeterJ do you mean "metaphysics doesn't change" in the meaning of the definition of metaphysics? I never stated such thing, I only referred to metaphysical views.

Comment: Fine. Of course individual view change. I was objecting to the idea that science had given us a reason to change any of them - except where they were metaphysically unsound in the first place. Metaphysics is notorious for never changing and in our academic world is heavily criticised for it. .

Comment: also, 'world view' is a phrase i don't like or understand and i've not seen analyzed in philosophy. it sounds like ideology

Comment: @another_name So you can not like what you don't understand? I strongly suspect your "non-ideology" is related to Carnap/Ayres/etc «The best metaphysics is no metaphysics»

Comment: not sure tbh @Rusi just saying i can't fit 'world view' into my life, practically. i think i can 'ideology', it's why i disagree with people on politics etc.

Comment: @another_name Note that worldview and ideology are synonyms (kinda) via the German origin  [Weltanschauung](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weltanschauung)

Comment: ah interesting thanks, i've seen that word before @Rusi

Answer (score 7):

The word "best" implies value judgments, and can't be evaluated independent of your goals for your worldview.  But there are clear practical and pragmatic reasons why science is currently a dominant worldview.  These include:

- Science is testable.
- Science is replicable.
- Science is attached to a large and growing body of useful, interconnected, internally consistent knowledge.
- Science is a foundation for a set of workable technologies that have become increasingly ubiquitous and unavoidable.

On the other hand science does have some crucial weaknesses:

- Science is amoral (note: NOT immoral).
- Science is blind to the large portion of human experience that is not susceptible to its analyses.
- Science is giving us power beyond our ability to use it wisely, thus resulting in an increasingly destructive impact on our world and each other.

I personally think it's crucial to find a worldview that addresses science's weaknesses.  But it won't go far unless it can also build on, harmonize with, compete with, or otherwise account for science's strengths.

Comment: Another weakness - Hume's induction problem. Pragmatism *might* have solved it, but then the new induction problem arises.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss That's a problem you and I, as philosophers, might care about, but it's not directly hurting science among the general public.  The strengths and weaknesses I listed above are all ones with immediate practical implications.

Comment: Can we say 'harmonize' rather than 'compete'?  Even the Pope (finally, just this last couple centuries) agrees that there is no reason for useful mythologies to compete with science.  We just need to keep it in its proper place.

Comment: @jobermark - edited.  It's a little clunky, but your point is well taken.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start by answering the concrete question that I'll paraphrase as

> do you need a scientific approach to do academic research?

The answer for a large number of fields, including philosophy, is no. There is a lot of academic work published that has no touching points to anything remotely scientific. There is also a fair amount of research that probably should be more scientific than it is but that's a separate matter.

Next I'll answer the question, again paraphrased

> is a scientific approach the only valid approach to understanding?

Again the answer is no. I can say this categorically because science is inherently limited. Specifically, the scientific method cannot be applied to any phenomenon that is not repeatable and measurable or has effects that are repeatable and measurable. As such, any attempt to understand something that cannot be repeatably tested cannot, by definition, be scientifically understood.

Thirdly, I'll try to answer the question in the title

> Is science really the best solution we have for our world view and analysis?

The answer depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you are interested in building understanding of the world such that you can better predict the future then, yes, science is currently the best approach we have. I mean this is the sense that it is the approach that has had the most success in this endeavour. It doesn't necessarily follow that it's the best in an optimal sense just that we have not discovered a more effective approach.

There are, however, other definitions of *best*. For example, many people have a need to feel that there is purpose to their life. Science has been singularly useless at providing comfort to these people. If this is your aim then science is not the best worldview.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. My concern about this "had the most success" is stated in Husserl's "Crisis of European Sciences and Transcendental Phenomenology" (well, more precisely, the "Crisis of European Sciences" article).

Comment: @YechiamWeiss Husserl's crisis is that science hasn't helped find the *meaning in human existence*. That's just another way of stating my final paragraph. And he's quite correct, it hasn't. Whether it could is somewhat debatable. My view is that it could be used to answer the more basic question of *is their a purpose beyond self perpetuation*, but it's hard to see science getting to what the purpose may be, assuming it finds there may be one.

Comment: that's part of the issue, but most of the first part of the "Crisis" is about science being praised because it has *merely* been the most successful, empirically-wise, predictions. Husserl basically says that we don't have anything to do now that we're "stuck" with science, and we have to find another way to think of the world, hence creating the "Transcendental Phenomenology". And on a different note, science (or, populized science) does claim to find a "meaning" (or more precisely, not find) - the theories of ET, BBT, and QM brings science to the conclusion that nihilism is the...

Comment: ... actual "hard" truth. Which since got us to optimistic nihilism - that we actually don't have a purpose, but we *should* do good.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss The lack of meaning is an untested hypothesis i.e. not science yet. I would speculate that, were one so inclined, a model of self preservation could be established and back tested against many species. We could then establish how far we are from said model. If, say, it showed that we were the only species with a significant discrepancy, one could argue that it follows that self preservation is not sufficient to classify our existence.

Comment: while it's indeed not a tested hypothesis (though how would you test lack of meaning?), it still is the most popular hypothesis currently, and it doesn't look like it can be easily dismissed, nor will it be able to be actually proven (at least scientifically, as you say. Though the combinations of randomness in QM and and evolution randomness in ET does seem to be the most "proven" facts that support these claims, which is a lot nowadays).

Comment: @Alex: Your view on what science is or isn't is probably too limited. You can't test for infinity, yet it's a useful and scientifically accepted concept that is widely used in mathematics for example. It has its applications to gain insight.

Comment: @jjack indeed you cannot test for infinity which is why scientists jump through hoops to remove infinities. Maths isn't science, it's a tool used by scientists. If something can't be tested, or it's consequences can't be tested, it's not science. A corollary is that, just because a scientist does something, it doesn't make it science. String theory currently falls into the latter class for example.

Comment: @Alex: So in physics, who would be the scientist? The theoretical physicist or the experimental physicist? I agree on string theory. It just seems esoteric and it's possibly more difficult than necessary. I disagree on math however. It's consequences are tested over and over.

Comment: @jjack They're both scientists (usually). Science is about testable hypotheses. Division of labour between the 2 parts is perfectly valid. String theory isn't unscientific because its esoteric or difficult. It's, currently, unscientific because its untestable. If a formulation of it was discovered that was tested then it would be scientific.

Comment: @Alex: But the consequences of string theory on a different level would be testable, right? On the level of current knowledge. Then it would just be a question of how far the consequences are removed from the theory.

Comment: this is the best answer, imho, though doesn't cite much philosophy!

Comment: Could anyone give an example of a scientific world-view? It would have to deal with metaphysics to be plausible. I've almost never come across a scientific world-view in the natural sciences. They're usually just a few physical theories surrounded by a hazy cloud of arbitrary guesswork and opinion.  . .

Comment: @PeterJ If you mean an entirely self consistent world view with no gaps in our knowledge then the correct answer is no, there's no such scientific world view. The correct scientific world view is a few physical theories interspersed with opinion, guesswork and, crucially, gaps.

Answer (score 2):

There are entire tracts of questions to which science cannot provide answers, by its own terms.  By a modern standard the assertions of any science must be testable (more specifically "[falsifiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Popper#Falsifiability/problem_of_demarcation)") or must abstract the content of a body of other testable assertions to provide a stable [paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigm#Scientific_paradigm) that guides further research.

Clearly questions about the mind *per se*, as opposed to behavior or the brain are not testable assertions, and no paradigm about them will meaningfully lead to testable theories.  Clearly all questions of meaning and purpose cannot be testable assertions, except to the extent they are simplified down to questions of behavior.  Clearly no moral theory is testable in terms of physical reality.

There is a domain completely outside scientific inquiry that is ultimately more important for any given individual to address.

This does not mean that the insights from the sciences can be completely ignored by anyone.  Our everyday lives are run by technology built on the basis of past science, and it would be hypocritical to disclaim the facts that cause that in favor of some purposely obstructionist philosophy, unless we really wish to be rid of those mechanisms and no longer benefit from the results of the process of science feeding technology.

But we do need, in this modern era to realize that we *always* draw implications about morality, deeper reality, the mind, and any number of other subjects from science by employing some other theory *outside science itself* and not accountable to the same rules.  Many of us too readily worship science and look to it to make commentary on more basic aspects of life about which it has no business speaking.

By applying philosophical investigation to science itself, we have evolved past the idea that our religion, our philosophy and our sciences can really make up a single thing that absolves us of the obligation to develop philosophically because we have adopted a 'scientific worldview'.  No such thing exists.

Contrary to the notions of people like [Richard Dawkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Dawkins), religion is not just immature science.  Instead, science makes for a destructive religion, hostile to both human psychology (as long noted by [C.G.Jung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungian_interpretation_of_religion) and our place in the world, as 'apologized' by [C.S. Lewis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._S._Lewis#Christian_apologist)).

Comment: I honestly agree with almost every statement in this answer, but I will note that: all those "clear" conclusions you come to about what cannot be answered by science - it isn't that clear. Epistemology isn't quantifiable (which means it can't be tested)? Ask Mitchiu Kaku and he'll say otherwise. And while you can disagree with him, it doesn't mean science isn't trying to "conquer" those "clearly untestable" fields - with the very clear, very demanding (and dominating), pragmatic statement -- science will eventually get there, like it conquered the fields that were previously left for religion.

Comment: (epistemology being a mere example of course).

Comment: This is something of a conspiracy theory: Any philosophy that makes physical facts impossible is wrong if the physics works.  That does not mean Michio Kaku is doing epistemology, much less that he has 'conquered' it,  But he does have something to say that epistemologists have to take seriously.  Roger Penrose has a similar delusion that he can actually do philosophy.  So does Dawkins, as noted. No one can keep egos from making people pronounce stupid things.

Comment: I'd say I agree with your points, only that I obviously didn't mean Kaku ever "conquered" anything, I'm merely stating the possibility and the ultimate fact that this is an aspiration of scientists (which they won't stop anytime soon, as far as how the science society acts). I'm not saying they are very smart by doing so, I'm saying they do it anyway and ultimately leading the western society believe that the natural sciences of the 20th century is going to have the final say on any field of knowledge we have.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss  And I would say that this is an aspiration for everyone -- to explain as much as possible within your chosen worldview.  But as I pointed out, if they speak on these issues, they are really always using theories outside science, whether they admit it or not.  'Scientism' -- naive realism projected from a technological basis, is not science.  It is a wrapper around science that pretends science can do things that it has been proven incapable of doing.  (You can't really agree if you missed the point.)

Comment: For instance, if science demands testability, it cannot contain moral content.  It can presume some kind of vague utilitarianism and look at behavior to see what makes people feel good.  Because we have fmri and that is now testable.  But then the utilitarianism is the morality, not the science...  The demand that our epistemology be the simplest one consistent with QFD is a choice to simplify the potentially meaningful philosophy away, and that is not a scientific decision.... primarily because 'simple' is not well-defined enough.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss  Maybe what you are objecting to, and calling 'a scientific worldview' is the pragmatic version of Enghtenment Neo-Liberalism -- the idea that things are resolved in 'the marketplace of ideas' according to some 'return on investment', which gives science an unfair leverage because it obviously produces the ability to control things, in a way that broader theorization does not?

Comment: OK so: first of all, yes, scientism is what I was referring to, and my point was that it happens a lot lately, and people thinks that's this is the truth (which is, to be honest, a different issue, but it is very much related). And your last point on pragmatism is also partially correct, when stating limits you control and saying other knowledge outside of those borders is inadmissible.

Comment: I just found a nice example of argument between a scientist and a philosopher about scientism (though the philosopher doesn't present the philosophy side as well as it could be, in my opinion) - https://www.google.co.il/amp/s/amp.theguardian.com/science/2012/sep/09/science-philosophy-debate-julian-baggini-lawrence-krauss#ampshare=https://www.theguardian.com/science/2012/sep/09/science-philosophy-debate-julian-baggini-lawrence-krauss

Comment: a well written answer, but i disagree with most of it e.g. "a domain completely outside scientific inquiry" makes no sense to me and you at least need to cite someone

Answer (score 1):

Science is just a *type* of knowledge (obtained via the scientific method). In contrast, there are other types of knowledge: religious knowledge (obtained from ancient books, which were written by mostly ignorant people), empirical knowledge (obtained by the senses), etc.

You can assess the validity of an assertion under the light of any type of knowledge. E.g. "is drinking beer good?" Religions might absolutely forbid it. Empirical knowledge would say it is very good above 2 liters, and science would state that a glass per week increases your chances of a long life. So far, as we know, science is the best type of knowledge (even if it is a subjective approach of our occidental, modern society).

Scientific knowledge is a very big and complex construct. Therefore Stephen Hawking would be ignorant about other areas of scientific knowledge, other than physics. You cannot expect absorbing *all* scientific knowledge. But scientific philosophy ensures anyone to access science, and the scientific method allows anyone to challenge and change any part of science. This current trend of *mandatory-academicism* required to be taken into account to make science is the response to our human tendency to profit from science and degrade it (Popper's pseudoscience) . Though, it is just a type of social corruption. Science should be open and we should be all valid subjects to challenge and change science.

The reason for science to be the preferred type of knowledge (as I called it, *socially subjective*) is that we consider it the best tool to increase our chances for a good life. But such is a trap: what is a *good life*? For us, occidental people, it means a *long life*. For other oriental cultures, it means a *happy life*.

Therefore, yes, other views of knowledge can also be valid: some ancient types of knowledge (as Buddhism) are by far excellent frames of reference to live *happy lives*. Occidental science is useful for tibetan monks, but their spiritual knowledge is the primary tool.

Naturally, some parts of spiritual knowledge will contradict science. Otherwise Buddhism would be a part of science. When both types of knowledge contradict, spiritual knowledge would rule.

Comment: This is basically @Allex' answer, but with more emphasis on the "other definitions of best". I like it, but a question - who says that "for us, occidental people, it means a long life"? (edit:) I'll rephrase - the reason occidental people are seeking longer life, is the thought that longer life means happier life (you get more time to spend on this world, you have more things to do, you get to be more with your grand/grand grand/children, you can take life more slowly, etc). That's ultimately one of the most debated question on prolonging life - would that really make us happier.

Comment: This is not related to the debate about why prolonging life, but all our social mechanisms point to that. Eutanasia and suicide are forbidden, our health system's goal is to keep us alive, living faster means living longer, etc. But for personal experience with oriental philosophy teachers (got that when I was 12), the goal is to be vulnerable, as any natural system, so the individual integrate into the environment, lives a slow life, which allows contemplation, a sense of eternity (which is impossible when living fast, or sick), and accepts any fate. Death is just natural, part of a cycle.

Comment: again, while all your points stand, the meta-point here is that ultimately the reason to seeking longer life is the thought that it'd make us happier.

Answer (score 1):

Wilhem Dilthey was a German philosopher and historian and he carefully distinguished between the natural and human sciences.

He said the task of the natural sciences was to uncover the law-based causal explanations of natural phenomena, and the task of the human sciences is to understand the organisational structures of human and historical life. It is not a sharp distinction, there are overlaps.

On this reading, emphasising the natural sciences misses out half of what is important for a comprehensive world view.

But more is true. One might argue, that the universe is much larger than the world of only human concerns, so the natural sciences must have a larger weighting, that they account for much more than half. Yet this misses out a truth. That we are human and what concerns is mostly are ourselves, our relationships with others, our individual and common history and also how we get on in life. On this reading, the human sciences must have a much larger weighting.

We solve this puzzle by relying on context. For all of us live not in an ideal world of knowledge but in an actual world of things, events and people with varying capacities and potentials; and what matters is how we guide ourselves through life and this depends on how they knock up against ourselves:

You might have trained as a scientist, and so science and it's progress concerns you more; you might have become a writer of historical novels and so what concerns you is how to make sense of history and of people in a historical situation. And so on.

Yet more is true. For there is more to knowledge and to the understanding than the sciences, both human and natural. Dilthey, alongside the Romantics, points out the value of feelings. Feelings as attitudes allow is to evaluate the world. Our values express adjudicative attitudes based on feeling. Lived experience is important to understand what it means to live. Ortega y Gasset, the Spanish philosopher puts it more pithily:

> To live is to deal with the world, to aim at it, to act in it, to be occupied with it.

Man lives in a world, and he is, mostly, and at most times, worldly and this is the kind of knowledge he is mostly occupied with; and even when he knocks up against the sciences, it is mostly within this attitude - for example, for him to hold a phone is not to wonder at how it works but to gain an understanding of how it can be put to use for him and in this world.

Contemplation, that attitude that informs the sciences, both natural and human, happens rarely and fitfully, and then only for the few.

Comment: This is a rather refreshing take on the subject. And while I don't fully agree with the assumptions made here (and are discussed in other answers), I will say this - but even after all you've said, natural science DOES take the larger, if not the absolute, weighting, and allows itself to not only affect, but to practically dominate the other sciences.

Comment: @Yechiam Weiss: I can see why you say that, but I'm not so sure about that. Natural science has been around for a very long time, it generally thought to have begun in Ancient Greek, in the Ionian peninsula at Milesia. But to my mind, there were earlier intimations. And for most of that era it has been the activity of the few. What passes for natural science today, is mixed up with the effective power it has helped produce in the world, and I would call that technology. Most people that are interested in science are in fact interested in the power technology has shown it has.

Comment: They are interested in the fruit of the tree and not the tree itself. Man is a tool-using animal. And he is in danger of being over-powered by his tools.

Comment: I like how your comments fit very well into Chris Sunami's answer.

Comment: @Yechiam Weiss: Chris Sunami's answer is excellent.

Answer (score -1):

> Does science provide the most accurate depiction of reality for
>   analyzing and describing an accurate worldview?

When we step on each rung we feel we have got the most accurate depiction.  But we forget the fact that after a few  years our views that science has granted would also become old.   That means our views of reality is not accurate.  I would say science does not provide the most accurate depiction of reality.  Since reality is not a subject like other subjects I would say science certainly provides **the things for** realizing the reality. That is why some people can surpass scientists.  Realizing reality is possible but analyzing reality is never.

If one's world-view and analysis are **always** right, it means that peroson knows the ultimate truth.  Or you can say,  truth is coming out through him without any interruption.  Otherwise you can confirm that his is a wrong world-view and analysis.

All those who realized the ultimate truth, (in your words, "those who knew solution for our world view and analysis") are developed not by a particular science.  Instead, they tried to look into themselves (self realization).

If our science is for nurturing the ego in us, that science would never be be a good solution.  But some wise men who have found out the word in themselves, have used their own **method** for **eliminating** their ego.  Sometimes we wouldn't find any science in them.  If you wouldn't call it a pseudo-science, the answer to your question is, "it is a good solution".  I mean science, if it is capable in eliminating the ego in us, is really a good  solution.  I wouldn't say it is the best, because people in this world follow different paths for this. Actually their body becomes a medium for that.  Many people could do that without our science (what we call science).  Such people had said that everything was done by the Lord (or something else).

> can we have a non-science (or, as Popper would call it -
>   pseudo-science) view of the world as we analyze reality?

If you are ready to include the great consciousness in our science, I wish to say 'No'.  Otherwise I would say 'Yes'.

> Must all writing today be done only by qualified scientists; in order
>   to post academic articles?

How is it possible to confirm whether someone is qualified or not without any doubt?  Who made the qualified scientist qualified? Can we accept it without any doubt?

> Do we have to apply for every conceivable topic, an empiric, mostly
>   materialist, view in order to act in the 21th century academic world?

Do you feel that this world is purely materialistic?  If so, IMHO, that assumption is **wrong**.

If I say science is the only world-view we have in analyzing our world, that means truth seldom comes out from those who are ignorant about science. And it also means that the world-view of the people who know science is often right. From our daily experience we can understand this is nonsense.

So...

> SHOULD science be the only worldview we have in analyzing our world?

No.

Modern  science is developing day by day.  Yet people's world view and analysis haven't developed more than our ancestors had.

Truth is passing through everybody (or, truth is there in everybody even in a sinner). Our ego is the main obstacle in creating a good world-view and analysis.